# Inline script on html not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to recreate a static HTML and bootstrap portfolio into React with components and jsx. The other parts of the code is working great except this part, so I decide to keep that in the HTML, but now its saying chart is not defined. I can see all the texts and background color, except the animation , which is hidden and in console give **Chart** is not defined

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Jay chacko </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/Chart.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>


     <!--SKILLS DESCRIPTION -->
     <div id="skillswrap">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
          <h5>SKILLS</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
          <canvas id="javascript" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
          <p>Javascript</p>
          <br>
          <script>
           var doughnutData = [
             {
              value: 55,
              color:"#1abc9c"
             },
             {
              value : 30,
              color : "#ecf0f1"
             }
            ];
            var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("javascript").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
          </script>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
          <canvas id="bootstrap" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
          <p>Bootstrap</p>
          <br>
          <script>
           var doughnutData = [
             {
              value: 80,
              color:"#1abc9c"
             },
             {
              value : 10,
              color : "#ecf0f1"
             }
            ];
            var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("bootstrap").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
          </script>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
          <canvas id="wordpress" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
          <p>jQuery</p>
          <br>
          <script>
           var doughnutData = [
             {
              value: 40,
              color:"#1abc9c"
             },
             {
              value : 35,
              color : "#ecf0f1"
             }
            ];
            var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("wordpress").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
          </script>
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3 centered">
          <canvas id="html" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
          <p>HTML/CSS</p>
          <br>
          <script>
           var doughnutData = [
             {
              value: 95,
              color:"#1abc9c"
             },
             {
              value : 20,
              color : "#ecf0f1"
             }
            ];
            var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("html").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
          </script>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
          <canvas id="photoshop" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
          <p>Angular Js</p>
          <br>
          <script>
           var doughnutData = [
             {
              value: 65,
              color:"#1abc9c"
             },
             {
              value : 30,
              color : "#ecf0f1"
             }
            ];
            var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("photoshop").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
          </script>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
          <canvas id="illustrator" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
          <p>React</p>
          <br>
          <script>
           var doughnutData = [
             {
              value: 50,
              color:"#1abc9c"
             },
             {
              value : 50,
              color : "#ecf0f1"
             }
            ];
            var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("illustrator").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
          </script>
         </div>
    <p>Other Skills - UNIX Commands, NPM, Gulp, bower packages, Web packs </p>
    <p>Other Soft Skills - NOSQL,MYSQL, Node JS </p>
    <p>Other Softer Skills - C#, Java, Objective C, MYSQL, PHP, Python </p>


       </div>
       <br>
      </div>
     </div>




    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may caused by loading `../assets/js/Chart.js` by browser **asynchronously**.

Try adding a `console.log(Chart)` in the beginning of your code (after loading Chart.js file) and see if it prints in console.

If it exist then it's not an issue with loading it in first place. (And this answer may not help you)

If it shows `undefined`, type `Chart` in your browser console and see if it loaded now asynchronous and defined. If it show up, you have to make sure Chart is loaded then run your code.

Comment: it is saying not defined . if you dont mind taking a look at it https://www.dropbox.com/s/552xpfs3ubggrmd/portfolio.rar?dl=0